# How to show message asynchronously on deliver a sms message?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm developing an android application that sends an sms message from a window (Activity) then moves to another window(Activity). I'm trying to display a message to the user how is seeing another activity that the message is delivered.
I imagine the solution would be to it fire a thread that send the message and and wait until it's delivered and show a toast or Dialog. but I don't know if it's right or how to do that.
pls help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sendDataMessage` has following parameters for that:

`sentIntent` - if not NULL this PendingIntent is broadcast when the message is sucessfully sent, or failed.

`deliveryIntent` - if not NULL this PendingIntent is broadcast when the message is delivered to the recipient.

[edit] - example how to create pending intent

```
final PendingIntent sentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, SmsSendCheck.class), 0);
```

`SmsSendCheck` - this is a special activity to show your Toast

Answer (score 0):

Toast is a good way. Otherwise, when your PendingIntent was broadcast after SMS was sent, display something in the current Activity.

Comment: thanks for answering pending intent is in other activity. how to display Toast while the work is in another activity

Comment: See here for how to do either: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511630/smsmanager-and-pending-intent